# REGEX matching 2 words in a column

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a regex pattern in a that needs to contain the words **trilogy** and **blank**.

I have tried :
`trilogy | blank`

The match is unsuccessful

Have attached a screenshot below of the input field!)

[regex input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyj0r.png)

Comment: `(trilogy|blank)` maybe?

Comment: The `|` means OR and the space will also be matched

Comment: `(trilogy).+(blank)|(blank).+(trilogy)` Give this a try

Comment: If lookarounds are supported `^(?=.*\btrilogy\b)(?=.*\bblank\b).+$`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
(\btrilogy\b.+\bblank\b)|(\bblank\b.+\btrilogy\b)
```

`\b` makes sure you match word boundaries (e.g. it won't match `blanket`).